# Why doesn't \textit work over multiple lines in tabbing?

Tags: line-breaking, italic, line, tabbing

If I have text in italics over two lines in the environment `tabbing`, only the first line is italic and the second line is upright. Also, the compilation has errors. Why is that? How can I make `\textit` work over multiple lines in `tabbing`?

I use LuaLaTEX.

The following is a minimal example. It was a part of something greater abstracted in macros, but I removed things and changed the text for maximum simplicity.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabbing}
        \textit{line being in italics \\
            line supposed to be in italics}
    \end{tabbing}            
\end{document}
```

[image: italic text on the first line but upright on the second line]

It showed these errors:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.6             line supposed to be in italics}
                                             
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<recently read> \egroup 
        
l.6             line supposed to be in italics}
                                             
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

Comment: tabbing "cells" like tabular cells are in a group. So ``\itshape line being in italics \= next \=next \\`` will stop italic at the tab position.

Comment: You can add two `\itshape` to the beginning of two lines as a workaround. (Or `\textit` wraps two lines separately.)

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry How can I have a macro which adds a `\itshape` at the beginning of every line of its input?

Comment: put `\itshape`  before `\begin{tabbing}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is there an environment similar to `tabbing` but without cell groups? I use it for aligning code listings, so the only tabs I use are left-aligning. Normal packages for code listing aren't viable because their options for alignment are very limited, especially with proportional fonts. Something inserting the correct amount of whitespace at the beginnings of lines would work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That wouldn't work. Only a part of the text in `tabbing` is supposed to be italic. I use it for syntax highlighting. [The actual usage is close to this.](https://pastebin.com/rx8Hqc6Y)

Comment: @matj1 I've used latex for over 30 years and I don't think I have ever found a use for tabbing, but anyway just use `\itshape` (not `\textit`) at the start of each cell, just as you would for `tabular`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there a way to reliably align code in a proportional font other than `tabbing`?

Comment: Please don't use `minimal` for MWEs. Despite the name, it isn't suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Your MWE can be solved using `tabto`. For code listings in a macro it could another history. XY problem? Ask always for the right path to reach your final goal, not why a wrong way took you to an unexpected place.

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,parskip} % just for dummy text
\usepackage{tabto}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]\par
\TabPositions{3cm, .6\linewidth}
   \tab {\itshape  line being \tab in italics \par
   \tab  line supposed        \tab to be in italics}  or not \par
   \tab just using            \tab one \verb+\itshape+\par    
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I created a new question for that: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683350/how-can-i-align-code-listing-with-a-propotional-font