# How can I align code listing with a propotional font?

Tags: listings, alignment, code, syntax-highlighting, tabbing

I'd like to typeset some code with a proportional code with alignment. How can I do it? The capabilities of `listings` to align are limited, and I was using `tabbing`, but it causes problems because every tab cell is its own group.

The code could look like this:
[image: example of some Racket code in a proportional font with alignment]

How can I typeset that? I want these features:

- low markup overhead – Having an instance of an environment for every case of alignment is tedious.
- option to effectively syntactically highlight – If I change the font in `tabbing`, the change can't last beyond the next tab stop or line break. ([See this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683263/why-doesnt-textit-work-over-multiple-lines-in-tabbing))

Almost all alignment which I do is of the beginning of the line, so a solution inserting the correct amount of whitespace before it would be OK. A clone of [spaceship-mode](https://github.com/tenbillionwords/spaceship-mode), which sets the width of the space to the width of the character above for every space at the beginning of the line would work. Having `\wall` and `\return` from [nath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nath) in normal text would work, I think.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use a proportional font rather than a fixed-width font? In general, most code is shown in fixed-width, and most people looking at it want it in fixed-width.

Comment: @enkorvaks Yes, typography. I dislike monospaced fonts because I think that, if ‘i’ has the same width as ‘M’, it doesn't look good. I want to not be limited by what people expect. Otherwise, I would be writing in Word. If Donald Knuth didn't have a similar attitude, ΤΕΧ wouldn't exist.